# Counting particular solutions to integer partition of a certain number.

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic

I need some assistance with my undergraduate discrete mathematics course. I have already solved Q1 and am having issues with question 2.

Essentially I have $x_1+x_2+x_3....+x_8=78$

Where $x_1, \ldots, x_8$ are in the set of Natural Numbers

Therefore in Question 1

It asks me to find how many solutions if...

$x_i \geq 8$ for all $1\leq i\leq8$

This is trivial, I solved it my answer is ${21\choose 7}$

Essentially I accounted $21 = 78*8*8$ and $7 = 8-1$

Now I am having issues with **Question 2**

It states

$x_1 \geq 17 $ $x_i \displaystyle \equiv  i \; (\mathrm{mod} \; 7)$ for all $1\leq i \leq 8$

How would I find the number of solutions that satisfy this condition using combinatorics and counting?

I am open to other methods of solving it (perhaps algebraically).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change "Solving a counting problem with modulo operator, in regards to a mathematical equation" into "Counting particular solutions to integer partition of a certain number", in paticular it is essential to have the keywords "integer partition".

Comment: I recommend proofreading your own question more carefully and editing it. You write $21 = 78*8*8$ which is obviously not true; I think you meant $21 = 78 - 8\times 8 + 7.$ You also (according to the way your text formats) wrote $x_1 \geq 17\ x_i$, which is an impossible condition. I think I see what you meant (these are parts of two entirely different expressions) but you need better punctuation or formatting so that people can see this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $0$ is not a natural number, define new variables
$$y_1=(x_1-1)/7,y_2=(x_2-2)/7,\dots,y_6=(x_6-6)/7,y_7=(x_7-7)/7,y_8=(x_8-\mathbf{1})/7$$
Then the equation becomes
$$7(y_1+\cdots+y_8)+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+1=78$$
$$y_1+\cdots+y_8=7$$
where the $y_i$ may be any nonnegative integer except that $y_1\ge3$ from $x_1\ge22$. Let $z_1=y_1-3$, then we have an equation where all variables are only constrained to be nonnegative integers:
$$z_1+y_2+\cdots+y_8=4$$
Then stars and bars gives the number of solutions to this problem, and thus the original problem, as $\binom{11}4=330$.